# Xpath - check all elements have sub elements

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery

Given the document

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c/>
        <d/>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c/>
        <d/>
   </b>
</a>
```

Is there any boolean xpath you can write that checks that all b nodes contain a c node. I tried

```
boolean(//a/b/c)
```

but this only checks that at least one of the nodes contains a c node, not ALL of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `//a/b[c]` would match all `b` elements having at least one `c` child element.

Though I would assert that there are 0 `b` elements not having `c` as a child:

```
count(//a/b[not(c)]) = 0
```

Comment: That still does not tell you if all b elements had a c element, it just picks out the one where that is the case

Answer (score 2):

Formulating the query as `not(//a/b[not(c)])` (instead of `count(...) = 0`) makes sure that the processor can stop after finding the first counter-example instead of having to count all of them.

If you want to be more explicit (but also a bit more verbose), you can use a [quantified expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-quantified-expressions):

```
every $b in //a/b satisfies $b/c
```

Comment: Good point -- but processors can in principle notice when a test has the form `count(...) = 0` and compile your two expressions down to the same compiled code.  I believe some do.

Comment: I know that BaseX does (and I'm confident Saxon does, too), but I would not count on such an optimization unless I know which processor is used. There are a lot more XQuery implementations than sophisticated XQuery optimizers. ;)

Comment: Quite true.  But, you know, speaking for myself, the cost to me in programmer-time of reading the double-negative swamps the likely cost of execution, so I would consider such a revision only if the test in question turned out to matter enough to keep me waiting repeatedly.  The first rule of [textual-level] optimization taught by Jon Bentley's great book on the subject is:  don't do it, if you don't *absolutely* have to.